# Shadows under StringGrid

Tags: delphi, persian, shadows, stringgrid

I have a form. On formshow, I initialize values of a field into stringgrid cells, but it shows a shadow under cell's texts. 
I've used Persian charaters for field's values.
I did the same with english values, but it works fine.
I appreciate any suggestions.

example of the output:

[image]

Comment: Looks as if you did implement a DrawCell and not filling the Rect before using TextOut.

Comment: s := (Sender as TStringGrid).Cells[ACol, ARow];
if Length(s) > 0 then
  begin
    drawrect := Rect;
    DrawText((Sender as TStringGrid).Canvas.handle, Pchar(s), Length(s), drawrect, DT_CALCRECT or DT_WORDBREAK or DT_LEFT);
if (drawrect.bottom - drawrect.Top) > (Sender as TStringGrid).RowHeights[ARow] then
(Sender as TStringGrid).RowHeights[ARow] := (drawrect.bottom - drawrect.Top)
else
begin drawrect.Right := Rect.Right;
(Sender as TStringGrid).Canvas.FillRect(drawrect);
DrawText((Sender as TStringGrid).Canvas.handle, Pchar(s), Length(s), drawrect, DT_WORDBREAK or DT_LEFT);
end;

Comment: I can not see the need for different handling depending on the lenght of s, however if you add `(Sender as TStringGrid) .Canvas.FillRect(Rect);` as first routine, you problem should have been one, since with enabled DefaultDrawing' the rext will have been already painted to the grid.

Comment: I used first solution and it worked correctly. Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 2):

With enaabled `DefaultDrawing` the text will be already rendered if you enter `OnDrawCell`.

Since you are calculating the needed rowheight in painting using `DT_CALCRECT` of `DrawText` you will have to calculated the `Rect` wich shall be filled/cleared with `FillRect`.
You can use `UnionRect` to get the final Rect which has to be filled (`FillRect` in the example).

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StringGrid1.Cells[1,1] := 'Hallo'#13'World';
  StringGrid1.Cells[2,2] := 'اهای' +13# + 'جهان';
end;

procedure TForm1.StringGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  S:String;
  drawrect,Fillrect : TRect;
begin
  s := (Sender as TStringGrid).Cells[ACol, ARow];
  drawrect := Rect;
  DrawText((Sender as TStringGrid).Canvas.handle, Pchar(s), Length(s),
      drawrect, DT_CALCRECT or DT_WORDBREAK or DT_LEFT);
  if (drawrect.bottom - drawrect.Top) > (Sender as TStringGrid)
      .RowHeights[ARow] then (Sender as TStringGrid)
      .RowHeights[ARow] := (drawrect.bottom - drawrect.Top);
  UnionRect(FillRect,Rect,DrawRect);
  (Sender as TStringGrid).Canvas.FillRect(FillRect);
  DrawText((Sender as TStringGrid).Canvas.handle, Pchar(s), Length(s),
        drawrect, DT_WORDBREAK or DT_LEFT);
end;
```